# Создание логинов с помощью запроса из таблицы MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

Переношу БД с одного сервера на другой (на тестовый, вне сети, подключить не представляется возможным). Разворачиваю бэкап базы, надо заново вносить логины для входа пользователей (в самой бд юзеры остались).
Каким должен быть запрос, чтобы автоматически создать логины на основе sys.Database_Principale?
Хочу взять из таблицы с юзерами логин и сид и у всех назначить назначить одинаковый пароль.

Comment: [Transfer logins and passwords between instances of SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/security/transfer-logins-passwords-between-instances)

Comment: @DenisRubashkin если я правильно понял, то создаю скрипты на первом сервере, выполняю, делаю бэкап, восстанавливаю на другом сервере и снова выполняю процедуру?

Comment: На первом сервере создаете две процедуры (обычно это в БД master). Выполняете, в результате получается скрипт, который или целиком или выборочно выполняете на втором сервере после поднятия бекапа.